# Updating data from a component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Basically I have a component which receives an array of objects. My goal is to update the data inside this component adding or removing some items from that array.
The code looks kind of like that:

```
export default {
    props: ['data'],
    methods: {
        add: function() {
            this.data.push({ someVal })
        },
        remove: function() {
            this.data = this.data.filter( item => {
                return item.val !== someVal;
            })
        },
    }
}
```

The tricky part for me is that "add" method works correctly and updates the data in the whole app. But "remove" method doesn't. Can anybody give me a clue?

Comment: Try to splice the array `this.data = this.data.splice(index, 1)`. You should add an index parameter to the remove function and fill it inside your v-for template. [vue index v-for](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable someVal in your filter is not defined so it will return the same items.

To remove an item you could use the splice() function.

Example:

```
remove: function(index) {
    this.data = this.data.splice(index, 1);
}
```

In your template use something like this:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in data" @click="remove(index)"></div>
```

Comment: **The variable someVal in your filter is not defined so it will return the same items.** It's just an example, the filter method does its job perfectly, but the data still doesn't update for some reason. However, your solution with the splice method works, thank you for your help. Unfortunatelly, I have my "v-for" loop in another component, so now I should think about how to pass the index to this one.

Comment: @stahlhammer Your parent component has a v-for and your child component uses a filter? That means your data structure is a multidimensional array? Besides that 'data' is used as a property. It is cleaner to emit an event to the parent component and update your data in there.